# How to use nature inspired algorithms like PSO as optimizers in keras model?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, particle-swarm

I am working on a keras model (Hierarchical attention network) to classify text into various categories. I have currently used Adam optimizer. I wish to use nature inspired algorithms like PSO, Cuckoo etc. as optimizers.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
word_input = Input(shape=(max_senten_len,), dtype='int32')
word = embedding_layer(word_input)
word = SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(word)
word = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(word)
word_out = AttentionWithContext()(word)
wordEncoder = Model(word_input, word_out)

sente_input = Input(shape=(max_senten_num, max_senten_len), dtype='int32')
sente = TimeDistributed(wordEncoder)(sente_input)
sente = SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(sente)
sente = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(sente)
sente = AttentionWithContext()(sente)
preds = Dense(6, activation='sigmoid')(sente)
model = Model(sente_input, preds)
opt = Adam(clipnorm=5.0)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['acc'])
```

Could anyone suggest me how to specify them as optimizers/ help with the relevant code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questions belongs to https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Keras optimizer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324140/how-to-change-keras-optimizer-code)

Comment: You will need to implement your own optimizer class (https://keras.io/optimizers/) for any which do not already exist. There are a few good questions on SO already showing how to go about this. If you need a template, take a look at the already implemented optimizers provided by keras/tensorflow